# Excel AddIn Command Open FilePicker Dialog and upload local file

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am developing with Excel AddIn and Command function, I want to achieve when I click a command, it will open a filepicker dialog and then able to choose image.

Is there any guide to achieve this in Excel AddIn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open select file dialog via js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215771/how-to-open-select-file-dialog-via-js)

Comment: Did you find a way?